# How to count the number of entries matched by a LDAP query without retrieving the records?

Tags: active-directory, ldap

How to count the number of entries matched by a LDAP query without retrieving the records?

I am trying several different LDAP filters on a big set of entries and for performance reasons I want to know only the number of returned entries, not to get them all.

Is this possible, how?

Answer (score 4):

No. The LDAP protocol does not provide support for counting. A server implementation could provide this information via an supportedControl or supportedExtension or some other "Feature", but I do not know of any that do this.

[UnboundID's SDK](https://www.unboundid.com/products/ldap-sdk/docs/javadoc/index.html) can perform the search and provide a searchResult count, but the search has to be completed before the count is complete. This would only save you the iteration of the results to perform the counting.

Comment: Performance-wise, best approach would be to limit the amount of information retrieved per record, i.e. do the search, but ask only for `distinguishedName` or `objectClass`. That should speed up at least the amount of data needed to be transferred from server to client.