# Softerra LDAP Browser - How to use LDAP SQL Query to get count in a folder

Tags: ldap

Softerra LDAP Browser - How do I use the LDAP SQL Query to get count in a folder.

Also, couldn't find any documentation on the Softerra queries possible. Does anyone have a link to the documentation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For documentation and support please see their [web site](http://www.ldapadministrator.com/resources/english/2011.1/sqlexamples.html).

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "DC=company,DC=com" 
REFERRALS TRUE;
```

The standard LDAP protocol does not provide support for counting, see  [How to count the number of entries matched by a LDAP query without retrieving the records?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26121363/how-to-count-the-number-of-entries-matched-by-a-ldap-query-without-retrieving-th)

Comment: Thanks it worked :-) I should have done a better job with checking the documentation. The link you send me was good.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps someone. The queries that I have used --

1. SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "OU=abc,OU=B2B,DC=company,DC=com" 
   REFERRALS TRUE;
2. SELECT * FROM "OU=abc,OU=B2B,DC=company,DC=com"
   REFERRALS TRUE;
3. SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "CN=TestAdmin,OU=Applications,DC=company,DC=com"  REFERRALS TRUE;
4. SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "OU=supplier,OU=B2B,DC=company,DC=com"  WHERE
   EXISTS $sn AND $sn="abc*"; REFERRALS TRUE;
5. SELECT COUNT(*) FROM
   "OU=supplier,OU=B2B,DC=company,DC=com"  WHERE EXISTS $cn AND
   $cn="abc123" REFERRALS TRUE;
6. SELECT * FROM
   "OU=supplier,OU=B2B,DC=company,DC=com" WHERE $whenChanged >
   CURRENT_DATE - 3 REFERRALS TRUE;
7. SELECT * FROM ROOTDSE WHERE EXISTS
   $ou AND $ou="B2B" REFERRALS TRUE;